# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k(k+\sin kx)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Since $$a_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k(k+\sin  kx)}=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+\sin kx}\right),$$

then

$$\frac{1}{n}-1\le\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}\right)\le a_n\le \sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

But we can not use the squeezing theorem because the limits of both hand sides do not equal.